# Falha ao Implementar Relatório com Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Estou com um relatório desenvolvido com o SQL Data Toosl porém ao tentar implementa-lo recebo a mensagem de que o servidor não foi localizado, mas ele está configurado nas propriedades do relatótio.

Segue como está hoje. Esta é a URL implementada no Reporting Service e que está acessivel
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui a configuração do relatório no SQL Data Tools

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui o erro que estou recebendo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não seria deixar só a raiz no ServerUrl e "Relatorios" no ReportFolder?

Comment: Foi exatamente isso. Falha de atenção minha que usei diretórios diferentes. Muito obrigado